# Converting Series of str to dates

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'm having a nightmare converting a series of strings to dates. This is a sample of my data:

```
net_due_date                from_date   clearing_date
0   2018-10-25 00:00:00.000 2017-06-06  2018-10-13 00:00:00.000
1   2018-09-27 00:00:00.000 2017-06-06  2018-09-30 00:00:00.000
2   2018-05-31 00:00:00.000 2017-06-06  2018-05-18 00:00:00.000
3   2017-12-22 00:00:00.000 2017-06-06  2017-12-08 00:00:00.000
4   2018-01-30 00:00:00.000 2017-06-06  2018-01-16 00:00:00.000
5   2018-07-31 00:00:00.000 2017-06-06  2018-07-31 00:00:00.000
6   2018-05-29 00:00:00.000 2017-06-06  2018-05-17 00:00:00.000
7   2017-12-14 00:00:00.000 2017-06-06  2017-12-08 00:00:00.000
8   2017-11-24 00:00:00.000 2017-06-06  2017-12-08 00:00:00.000
9   2018-09-27 00:00:00.000 2017-06-06  2018-09-13 00:00:00.000
10  2018-01-25 00:00:00.000 2017-06-06  2018-01-16 00:00:00.000
11  2017-11-24 00:00:00.000 2017-06-06  2017-11-30 00:00:00.000
12  2018-10-24 00:00:00.000 2018-01-09  2018-10-11 00:00:00.000
13  2018-01-22 00:00:00.000 2018-01-09  2018-10-10 00:00:00.000
14  2018-09-06 00:00:00.000 2018-01-09  2018-10-10 00:00:00.000
15  2018-10-24 00:00:00.000 2018-01-09  2018-10-10 00:00:00.000
16  2018-06-15 00:00:00.000 2018-01-09  2018-10-10 00:00:00.000
17  2018-04-10 00:00:00.000 2018-01-09  2018-10-10 00:00:00.000
18  2018-01-12 00:00:00.000 2018-01-09  2018-10-10 00:00:00.000
19  2018-01-24 00:00:00.000 2018-01-09  2018-10-10 00:00:00.000
```

These are the dtypes:

```
net_due_date     object
from_date        object
clearing_date    object
dtype: object
```

I'm trying to convert all of this data to the same format so I can run functions on it to calculate variance between dates.

The following code works fine on net_due_date:

```
df['net_due_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['net_due_date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
```

And a similar code works fine on from_date:

```
df['from_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['from_date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
```

However, clearing_date has some values in there that are 9999-12-31 and when I run the same code, I get the following error:

```
OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 9999-12-31 00:00:00
```

I have literally spent hours trying to fix this, the closest I have got being this link:
[Time Series, OOB Timestamps](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/timeseries.html#timeseries-oob)

But then I'm confronted with the following error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for //: 'str' and 'int'
```

To get around this, I have tried converting the column to an int first using to_numeric, but get another series of errors. I'm hoping someone has been in this problem before and can help because I cannot find anything online to fix this!

Comment: "9999-12-31" is most likely a way to indicate "as of" or "most recent", if this date is something you care about, you can change it to today, and if not, you can change them to Missing values, and the conversion should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`errors` argument](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) of the same method:

> **errors** : *{‘ignore’, ‘raise’, ‘coerce’}, default ‘raise’*
>
> - If ‘raise’, then invalid parsing will raise an exception
> - If ‘coerce’, then invalid parsing will be set as NaT
> - If ‘ignore’, then invalid parsing will return the input

This one line should do the trick for you:

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, errors='coerce'))

# results:
#    net_due_date  from_date  clearing_date
# ...
# 10   2018-01-25 2017-06-06     2018-01-16
# 11   2017-11-24 2017-06-06            NaT
# 12   2018-10-24 2018-01-09     2018-10-11
# ...
```

If necessary you can massage the `DataFrame` afterwards for the `NaT` values and transform to something meaningful to you, e.g.:

```
df.fillna(pd.datetime.now().date(), inplace=True)

#    net_due_date  from_date  clearing_date    
# 10   2018-01-25 2017-06-06     2018-01-16
# 11   2017-11-24 2017-06-06     2018-11-23 # <-- changed to today
# 12   2018-10-24 2018-01-09     2018-10-11
```

And just to confirm the `dtypes`:

```
net_due_date      datetime64[ns]
 from_date        datetime64[ns]
 clearing_date    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

Comment: giving this a go now.  is the lambda function the most efficient way to run this function? one thing i didnt mention is that i'm working with 55m rows

Comment: `lambda` is just an anonymous function, basically wrapping the `pd.to_datetime` to convert each columns being passed.  As far as efficiency goes I think this is probably decent as the functions being applied are rather minimal.  Give it a test and see the run time on your machine though.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that in your case all columns are of `String` type and contain dates
+ sometime time part. So the simplest choice is:

```
df = df.applymap(pd.to_datetime)
```

Run the below script converting a part of your source data:

```
import pandas as pd

dd = { 'net_due_date': [ '2018-10-25 00:00:00.000', '2018-09-27 00:00:00.000',
        '2018-05-31 00:00:00.000', '2017-12-22 00:00:00.000',
        '2018-01-30 00:00:00.000' ],
    'from_date': [ '2017-06-06', '2017-06-06', '2017-06-06', '2017-06-06', '2017-06-06' ],
    'clearing_date': [ '2018-10-13 00:00:00.000', '2018-09-30 00:00:00.000',
        '2018-05-18 00:00:00.000', '2017-12-08 00:00:00.000', '2018-01-16 00:00:00.000' ] }
df = pd.DataFrame(data=dd)
df = df.applymap(pd.to_datetime)
```

When you execute `df.info()`, you will get (a part of the printout):

```
Data columns (total 3 columns):
net_due_date     5 non-null datetime64[ns]
from_date        5 non-null datetime64[ns]
clearing_date    5 non-null datetime64[ns]
```

For demonstration purpose, you may add `print(df)` both before and after
the conversion.

As far as "very big" years are concerned, Pandas converts dates with
year in the range between 1677 and 2262. So maybe as the first step
you should change such out of range dates to e.g. 2250.